# CSS - Text over image

Tags: html, css, image

I have a image like this:

[image]

The site is responsive. So the question below need to follow the image size on a figcaption.

I need to know if it´s possible to put both icon inside de image. Both text (3 lines to the left, 3 lines to the right) and a pipe ico to divide the text using HTML/CSS.

Does anyone knows how can I do this?

Comment: What have you done so far to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it also responsive like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DaSa7/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150/FFF/000" />
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="left"><img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/AEA/000" />
            <div class="box-text">
                <h2>Endereco</h2>
                <h2>Test1</h2>
                <h2>Test2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50/AEA/000" />
            <div class="box-text">
                <h2>Endereco</h2>
                <h2>Test1</h2>
                <h2>Test2</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
 }
html,body{height:100%;}
img{width:100%;height:auto;}

.container{height:100%;}

.panel {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;     
}
.panel-body {
    height: 50%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;
    background:red;
}
.left,.right{
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
.left img,.right img{
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
.box-text{float:left;}
```